# Where to execute code that comes after retry in rxjs Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on an HTTP interceptor & I want to Logout my user if the refreshToken API fails **after the retries.**

```
    return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
      switchMap((token: any) => {
        console.log(token);
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken);
        return next.handle(this.addToken(req, token.accessToken));
      }),
      retry(3), //Tries the refreshToken() API if it returns with an error.
      catchError(error => {
      //If the refreshToken() API never returns a successful response, I want to Logout.
        this.authService.Logout();
        return throwError(error);
      }
    );
```

My question is, am I doing the catchError correctly? I only want it to happen after it retries 3 times and still fails, but I'm worried that it will catchError before retrying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work only after `retry`. Also, you can put it not to `catchError` but to subscribe error callback.
Here is an simulation of your use-case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kbfkq7

First subscription fails several times but is below `retry` point - so it resolves.

Another one is above - so `catchError` and error callback are emitted.